# User input in panda, Can't stop the loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Please see my below code, I'm trying to use user input to select specific rows within a dataframe. I'm not sure if it's my loop that is causing the issues? As when I run the code outside of the function the code seems to work. Any help would be great.
Thanks

```
  def option3():
        print("---------------------------")
        print("please select from the following options")
        print(Ndata[" workclass"].unique())
        print("---------------------------")
        loop3 = True
        while loop3:
            print("---------------------------")
            Op1 = input('Please enter first working class: ')
            Op2 = input('Please enter second working class: ')
            print("Options selected ", Op1, "&", Op2)
            print("---------------------------")
           
            if Op1 and Op2 in Ndata[" workclass"]:
                    loop3 = False
                    sub = Ndata.loc[Ndata[" workclass"].isin([Op1, Op2])]
                    print("---------------------------")
                    print("PLease select frome the following")
                    print("[1] Most educated countries ")
                    print("[2] Marital status ")
                    print("---------------------------")
                    Op3 = int(input("PLease enter 1 or 2 : "))
                    loop4 = True
                    while loop4:
                        if Op3 == 1 or 2 :
                                loop4 = False
                      
                        else:
                            print('PLease select 1 or 2')
                
            else: 
                print("Please check", Op1, "&", Op2, " are in the working class")
                print(Ndata[" workclass"].unique())
```

Comment: The format of ```if Op1 and Op2 in Ndata[" workclass"]:``` isn't valid.  Chage to ```if Op1 in Ndata[" workclass"] and Op2 in Ndata[" workclass"]:```

Comment: also, you never set ```loop3 = False``` or break out of the ```while loop3:``` loop.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).